# Android - Mobile network settings menu (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, networking, settings, android-4.2-jelly-bean

following code is not working for Jelly Bean (Android 4.1):

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
final Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Instead to start setting , it doesn´t nothing, any idea how to solve it?

Here is solution:

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.MobileNetworkSettings");
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you guys : )

Comment: try after adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Answer (score 5):

try as:

```
final  Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if this not work then easy way attach your device to debugger and launch ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS setting manually then see in log for package name and Activity Name launched by system

Comment: check activity name in log sonething like com.android.phone/.Settings ??

Answer (score 0):

The code below is much more simple and tested on Gingerbread (2.3.7) and JB (4.1.2)

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS), 0);
```