# Mobile Network Settings in Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

My app should open Mobile Network Settings activity. Everything works fine except devices with Android 4.1 which crash after attempt to open Settings

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
final ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Stack trace after crashing:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.phone/.Settings } from ProcessRecord{41b83198 ...
```

Any ideas? Could it be because of the manifest?

UPDATE:

Seem that the problem was solved here: 
[Android - Mobile network settings menu (Jelly Bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291387/android-mobile-network-settings-menu-jelly-bean)

The thing is to change "com.android.phone.Settings" to "com.android.phone.MobileNetworkSettings"

Comment: What device are you testing this on, as [in some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS)

Comment: The problem was found on Nexus S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to try

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

This thing is working for me in android 4.1.2,
might be they fixed this issue in 4.1.2